# During B1/B2 visa interview, is it problem to request that the visa starts several days before the conference

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas

I have an interview for B1/B2 visa application to attend a conference in US. Normally, the conference will take place in Texas, but I will first visit Atlanta 5 days before the conference (to meet my previous professor). I wonder during the interview if it is okay to request that the visa starts several days before the conference.

I have registration receipt for the conference which actually does not tell the exact start date. I also have the email (printed) that states the acceptance of my presentation and the start date of the conference. I wonder if I should keep the second document away unless I am not asked for?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

American B1/B2 visas are valid for travel [from the very day it is issued](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/visa-expiration-date.html).

> A visa issued for a single entry (denoted on the visa under “Entries”
> with the number 1) is valid, or can be used **from the date it is issued**
> until the date it expires to travel to a U.S. port-of-entry one time.
>
> A visa issued for multiple entries (denoted under “entries” with a
> certain number (2, 3, etc.) or “M” for multiple/unlimited entries) is
> valid, or can be used **from the date it is issued** until the date it
> expires to travel to the U.S. port-of-entry as many times as your visa
> states, provided that:

You do not need to request it explicitly. The consular officers typically understand that people travel some days before their event and that people may have other minor reasons for travel in addition to the main reason for applying.

Make sure you carry all the documents related to your travel on you, basically the documents supporting your trip.

Comment: thank you very much sir! I will have conference registration receipt as well as the presentation acceptance email [printed].